# Contar Valores com PHP e SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Galera, Boa tarde.

Estou com a seguinte dúvida.
Tenho um questionário com 10 perguntas, as respostas para essas perguntas podem ser de 0 à 5, gostaria de fazer um while sair contando as respostas.

Pensei na seguinte forma e ir concatenando conforme o loop fosse se repetindo.

```
$inicio = 1;

while($inicio <= 10){

$query = "&#36query$inicio";
$row = "&#36row$inicio";



$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carrefour WHERE notapergunta1=1 AND statusPesquisa=2");
$row  = mysql_num_rows($query);





$inicio++;
}
```

Comment: nao entendi sua pergunta pode ser mais especifico? o que quer contar mesmo? se poder meter mais detalhes talvez possa ajudar.

Comment: Então @Hardcorder, vou tentar ser mais específico possível. Tenho um questionário em HTML e CSS com 10 perguntas, quando as pessoas respondem esse questionário ele é cadastrado em uma tabela as respostas. Estou desenvolvendo um gráfico para este questionário e estou usando ChartsJS para gerar estes gráficos, a dúvida é a seguinte: Esse questionário pode ter notas de 0 à 5, logo eu gostaria de criar um while onde percorresse minha tabela para gerar esse gráfico automatizado, e não ter que fazer uma query para cada pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Eu não entendo muito de PHP, mas você pode colocar com as seguintes implementações de SQL:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM nometabela WHERE Resposta = "1";
```

Com este código você poderá dar um echo em seu PHP e descobrir a quantidade de respostas!

Comment: Coloquei o código no PasteBin para você ter uma noção: http://pastebin.com/aaVhQnsi

Comment: Conseguiu implementar o Select?

Comment: Consegui Vinicius, porém precisava que fosse percorrido em um while.

Comment: Não dá pra fazer usando o for?

Comment: André, usei um while, veja no pastebin  http://www.pastebin.com/aaVhQnsi